# Firefox sync does not work as expected

Tags: firefox, sync

I have compiled and started the firefox sync server as explained on [this page](http://docs.services.mozilla.com/howtos/run-sync.html).
I am running the server on my desktop.

From Firefox, I have created an account on my desktop.
I have paired my laptop with my desktop (generated the key on the laptop, entered
it on the desktop, and the account is now visible on the laptop as well).

Now, when I try to synchronize my bookmarks, nothing happens.

Here is my procedure:

1. On the laptop, I go to Firefox Preferences -> Sync.
2. I choose the account and the option Manage Account.
3. Under Manage Account I choose Reset Sync -> Replace all data on this computer with
   my Sync data.
4. I get the message: Warning: The following Firefox data on this computer will be deleted: 122 bookmarks. Firefox will then copy your Firefox Sync data to this computer.

At this point I press Next and I would expect the bookmarks from my desktop Firefox to appear in my laptop Firefox. Instead, nothing happens: the dialog closes and when I look at my bookmarks nothing has changed.

I have also tried pushing my desktop bookmarks to the laptop using the option (on the desktop): Replace all other devices with this computer's data.
In this case, a window appears with the message

```
Confirm
Warning: The following devices will be overwritten with your local data:
```

and the list of devices is empty, even though my laptop is connected. Again, if I click on Next, nothing happens (the bookmarks on the laptop are unchanged).

Am I doing something wrong? Or how do I mirror my desktop bookmarks to my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

If I could remember ... I did it yesterday between different distros at the same PC
First I created a sync account from the Firefox tool menu. I chose my Google e-mail, this is important because it is easier. Then I restarted the PC to another distro, once again I returned to the first distro, I got the 3 little keys but these keys do not work always. Finally I succeed with the large single key: d-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx., between several distros.

Comment: I have one desktop and one laptop. Both are running Ubuntu 10.04. The sync server runs on the desktop. I have tried the 3-keys solution. Why is it easier with a google account? Shouldn't it work the same with any valid email address?

Comment: Then perhaps you should reinstall Firefox, to do it very easily see the question: How to install real Firefox on Debian 6?

Comment: I have tried the Firefox sync between 4 distros and it is working fine. When I finish to modify any browser I just press the Tools/Sync now and Firefox sync choose the best solution. Probably the Google account is not better than others but it goes quicker.